# 3D voxel visualizaiton in web browser

Tags: 3d, voxel

I have implemented 3D surface visualization in web browser by three.js, both for .vtk and .obj files. but now I want to do 3D voxel visualization in web browser, like nifti file. Any suggestions are appreciated.
Here is a shortcut pic:
[image: upper one is what i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the second, get an intensity file from corresponding NIFTI file, and then load it in BrainBrowser. but the first one, structural connectivity, maybe i can use DTI fibre bundle.